# A matrix as a sum of regular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If the field $\displaystyle F$ has an infinite number of elements then prove that every element in $\displaystyle F_{n}$ can be written as a sum of regular matrices.

$\displaystyle F_{n}$ is the set of all $\displaystyle n\times n$ matrices over $\displaystyle F$.

Is it enough if I prove that a matrix can be written as a sum of two invertible matrices?

If not, then how can I prove that **a matrix can be written as a sum of regular matrices?**

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of the symbol $F_n$. If it's the set of all $n\times n$ matrices over $F$, the standard notations are $M_n(F)$ and $F^{n\times n}$.

Comment: I have mentioned this in the question now.